# Cannot open database "C:\PROGRAM FILES\X\Y\Z.MDF" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-xxxxx''

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have created a windows form application. I have included a local dabase named Z.mdf.  In the app.config the connection string is like below:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ZConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Z.mdf;Integrated Security=false;Connect Timeout=30"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I run the application from visual studio,it works fine. But when I deploy the application with advanced installer, it gives the following error:

> Cannot open database "C:\PROGRAM FILES\X\Y\Z.MDF" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-xxxxx''

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Where do you set authentication credentials? Cant see where/what is setting it.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string specifies `Integrated Security=false;` so the login isn't using your Windows user account.

You need to either use `Integrated Security=true` or you need to specify a user id and password on your connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ZConnectionString"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Z.mdf;
    Integrated Security=false; user id=xyz; password=abc;Connect Timeout=30"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```